# Reading from a frequently write math function to new line file

Tags: python

Is it possible to write the next line with this code?
How to do that?
I want to read (n) line then do math to write (n+1), with unlimited looping.

```html
import time
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open("myfile.txt","r+")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        write.logfile ("5*2+1\n")
```

Comment: @MauriceMeyer but it only works 1 time, I need looping non stop read line n and then write n + 1.

Comment: Please share your code, otherwise nobody gets an idea what you are talking about

Comment: @MauriceMeyer this is my new question, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702899/how-to-reading-from-a-frequently-r-updated-file-with-python-code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using methods of file objects.

Here is the link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

You can use `seek`, `write` and `read` to achieve what you want.